# GWT Client Server Communication

Tags: gwt

I'm wondering whether it is at all possible to make the client ask the server for a given string, and incorporate it into another string ?

I don't see how to do that using the `async` approach.

Comment: Don't get the problem. For every js single page web-app there is only async communication. Can you explain a little bit more precise, what you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to i18n gxt XTemplates, but using a i18n file that is on the server side, so I'd like to inject the value in the template. So I'd like to be able to ask the server to i18n a given string, and give me the resulting value. Is that possible ?

Comment: Did you try using ResourceBundle in server side to get the i18n text from properties file??

Comment: Yes this is what I'm using, and it works, but how to inject it into the Xtemplate ? I was planning on using something like the custom formatters, with {stringToTranslate.translate()}, and then calling the service from the client with String translate(String). But this method requires to return a string, whereas gwt async services return void.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no really simple way to do this, because the i18n machanism of GWT replaces strings at compile-time and not at runtime.

You can try one of the following approaches:

1. Load the i18n in your entrypoint, store all messages in a local Map and create the Label etc, with the values from you cache. **PRO**: all GWT standard **CONS**: one request more, before you can show a translated page
2. Use  JSP and no HTML at serverside. Wthin you jsp can create a JSON from your
   message.properties and put it into your hostpage. **PRO**: You can synchronous read te values **CONS**: You will need to write a JSP which reads the properties for the correnct language, You will need to write a JSNI method to load the translated values.
3. Rethink, if you need a different way of translation. The built-in i18n will create tranlated versions of your app at compile-tim

I think I would use the second approach.